# Proper http function call for no return data

Tags: http

I missed a couple of decades of http development. Apparently there is some low-level error handling code for the case where:

A Request is sent (to run a remote file), but no file data is returned. [HTTP version of UDP?]

Any WebBrowser handles this automatically, when simply entering the URL to the particular file or clicking a hyperlink, and will run the remote file returning a blank page with nothing but the URL attached.

But attempting this from a command line interface, my HTTP code from 1986 is no longer valid.

Depending on the interface and its’ particular error handling code, i get any number of random error messages. Usually in the 400-500 range.
E.g.:   400, 405, 406, 408, 417
and sometimes time-out errors.
(log shows time-out occuring while waiting for a response, again depending on the interface, this may happen if or if not the file actually executes remotely)

So how does HTTP handle errors when there is no actual errors, header data, confirmation reciept, or anything else coming back?

(in 1986 we had to type a line of code to expect a response, this is a simple base level operation)

I am just unaware of the modern HTTP handler for this situation.
Or how to use it in the code

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This system was implemented as a hard-level security protocal. The file being executed may be either an html file that runs a local process, or a .php file that does the same. The URL’s are private, internal URL’s. The return data is disabled in the event someone gets ahold of a link or it is randomly discovered (by a web crawler or curious individual). To ensure that the data is not compromised.  This is a crucial system, wherein software based security such as that commonly used in modern http/https transactions is not sufficient to ensure security.

Comment: Sorry: “disabled” is the wrong word, the file data is set to NULL. when the interface has an expectation of something being returned before, after (or during) execution, an error returns.
This system is functional if used through a modern webbrowser, E, firefox, Safari, etc. i am looking for the actual code to handle this, such as an RPC that calls the execution of the remote file, or a command line http [request is not the word i want to use here] request. Of course it ‘must be’ some type of request, what i need to know is how to make that request without the expection of a response.